# Creating bridge in Linux, share network like VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, bridge, libvirt

I have a local are network  `192.168.1.1/24`. I use libvirt and I want my virtual machines to use this network also, at least a sub-network of it, such as `192.168.1.128/25`. However, all the libvirt bridge options creates another network, and I cannot set my them to use my network, VirtManager gives an error, and manually defining a forwarded network

```

```
 <network>
    <name>mynetwork</name>
    <bridge name="mybr0" />
    <forward mode="route" dev="em1"/>
    <ip address="192.168.1.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
      <dhcp>
        <range start="192.168.1.128" end="192.168.1.254" />
      </dhcp>
    </ip>
  </network>
```

```

It gives the following error:

```
virsh # net-start mynetwork
error: Failed to start network mynetwork
error: internal error: Network is already in use by interface em1
```

VirtualBox has an option to create a bridged connection, where it just gets IP from DHCP server at my router, and acts like another machine in my network. How can I achieve this? I tried manually creating a bridge with `bridge-utils` package, but no luck so far.

**EDIT:** I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That depends on which Linux distribution you are using. Different flavors handle that differently. So you should provide us with that information.

Comment: @Daniel I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can show you how to create a bridged connection in KVM, but there is a difference with respect to VirtualBox: the IP address of the guest machines is not assigned by the DHCP server, but is a static IP chosen by you, hopefully outside the DHCP pool.

If you use a cable connection, then [the libvirt Wiki page](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Altering_the_interface_config) shows how to bridge an ethernet interface with your VMs.

Please notice: the above only works for ethernet IFs. It is possible to bridge a wireless interface, but not this way.

[This nice post by Bohdi Zazen](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/bridge-wireless-cards/) shows how to do this. It uses arp-proxy to relay arp traffic to a specially crafted *tap* interface. There is only one outdated feature, the creation of the *tap* interface by means of the tunctl command/package. Do not do that, *iproute* can take care of that for you:

```
    ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root
    ip link set tap0 up
```

Otherwise, his solution works flawlessly.

If the thought of using a static IP is unbearable to you, you can NAT rather than bridge, as explained [here](https://shanetomlinson.com/2009/bridging-a-wireless-card-in-kvmqemu/).